# Custom distribution in scipy with pdf given

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I try to define a custom distribution with pdf given via scipy.stats

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous

class CustomDistribution(rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self, pdf=None):
        super(CustomDistribution, self).__init__()
        self.custom_pdf = pdf
        print "Initialized!"

    def _pdf(self, x, *args):
        if self.custom_pdf is None:
            # print 'PDF is not overridden'
            return super(CustomDistribution, self)._pdf(x, *args)
        else:
            # print 'PDF is overridden'
            return self.custom_pdf(x)

def g(x, mu):
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return mu * np.exp(- mu * x)

my_exp_dist = CustomDistribution(pdf=lambda x: g(x, .5))
print my_exp_dist.mean()
```

As you see I try to define exponential distribution wuth parameter mu=0.5, but the output is as follows.

> Initialized!
>
> D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:357:
>
> IntegrationWarning: The algorithm does not converge.  Roundoff error
>   is detected   in the extrapolation table.  It is assumed that the
>   requested tolerance   cannot be achieved, and that the returned result
>   (if full_output = 1) is    the best which can be obtained.
>   warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
>
> D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:357:
>
> IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been
>   achieved.
>
> 2.0576933609
>
> If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to
>   analyze    the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If
>   the position of a    local difficulty can be determined (singularity,
>   discontinuity) one will    probably gain from splitting up the
>   interval and calling the integrator    on the subranges.  Perhaps a
>   special-purpose integrator should be used.   warnings.warn(msg,
>   IntegrationWarning)

What should I do to improve this?

**NOTE:** The problem of computational accuracy is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6579).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want. An instance of the class must be given a value for the lambda parameter each time the instance is created. rv_continuous is clever enough to infer items that you do not supply but you can, of course, offer more definitions that I have here.

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import numpy

class Neg_exp(rv_continuous): 
    "negative exponential"
    def _pdf(self, x, lambda):
        self.lambda=lambda
        return lambda*numpy.exp(-lambda*x)
    def _cdf(self, x, lambda):
        return 1-numpy.exp(-lambda*x)
    def _stats(self,lambda):
        return [1/self.lambda,0,0,0]

neg_exp=Neg_exp(name="negative exponential",a=0)

print (neg_exp.pdf(0,.5))
print (neg_exp.pdf(5,.5))

print (neg_exp.stats(0.5))

print (neg_exp.rvs(0.5))
```

Comment: but how can I use _custom_ pdf in instance constructor?

Comment: You shouldn't do that because when you define either _pdf or _cdf the software uses the function signature that you have provided to obtain other information it needs to define methods such as rvs, if you don't define _rvs. You need one subclass of rv_continuous for each pdf/cdf that you want (up to parameters).

Comment: this is exactly what I need - I want software to calculate other methods automatically using my custom `pdf`. BTW why does my code calculates expectation of exponential distribution incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know anything about the internal workings of rv_continuous. I conjecture that it's unable to find the information that it needs when you place it where it doesn't expect to find it. Incidentally, when I remove the _stats method from the above code and re-run it, rv_continuous correctly calculates the mean and variance of the negative binomial for that parameter. Wish I could be more informative.

Comment: I suggest avoiding the use of any reserved keywords. I often use `lam` instead of `lambda`.